# How can I prevent anti-aliasing in Photoshop shapes and smart objects?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, anti-aliasing

I am simply drawing a shape using the shape layer tool, however no matter how many shapes I draw, when zoomed in there is always anti-aliasing

[image]

I know I can select fill pixels and then switch off anti-aliasing however I need to work with the shape layer tool for scaling. Any help would be great.

Comment: Alright if anyone see this I think I've figured it out.  In the shape layer tool dropdown menu, make sure the 'snap to pixels' is ticked on. It seemed to work for me

Answer (score 1):

You're really asking about two different things: smart objects and shapes. Photoshop will always anti-alias where it needs to, and snapping to the pixel grid only avoids that when your shape contains only vertical and horizontal lines.

A curve or diagonal will still be anti-aliased for on-screen viewing unless you explicitly turn it off, as you've noted in the question. Text and vectors are both displayed this way.

Smart Objects are *always* raster images in the Photoshop UI, even if the contents of the SO is a vector. Each time you scale a SO, it is re-rendered at the new resolution.

To export vectors as vector shapes, Save As a Photoshop PDF. The PDF format stores vector information in a way that can be used by other applications (such as a printer's RIP). Other applications treat a PSD as a raster image, regardless of its contents.